# summing numbers from array(java)

Tags: java

i am having hard time figuring out how to sum up all the immigrants( or any number in an array  ) in this 2d array and i cant think of an **efficient way to do so** other than summing all of the values which is rubbish in large quantities 
thanks in advance

### **here's my code :**

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object[][] data = { { "United States", 45785090, 19.8, 14.3 }, { "Russia", 11048064, 4.8, 7.7 },
            { "Germany", 9845244, 4.3, 11.9 }, { "Germany", 9845244, 4.3, 11.9 },
            { "Saudi Arabia", 9060433, 3.9, 31.4 }, { "United Arab Emirates", 7826981, 3.4, 83.7 },
            { "United Kingdom", 7824131, 3.4, 12.4 }, { "France", 7439086, 3.2, 11.6 },
            { "Canada", 7284069, 3.1, 20.7 }, { "Australia", 6468640, 2.8, 27.7 },
            { "Spain", 6466605, 2.8, 13.8 } };

    System.out.printf("%22s %12s %17s %14s\n", "contry", "immigrants ", "% world total ", "% population");

    for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        System.out.printf("%22s %12s %17s %14s\n", data[row][0], data[row][1], data[row][2], data[row][3]);
    }
    int totalIm ;
    for(int row= 0 ;row<  data.length;row++){

    }
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean summing them all? That sounds like the right way to do it for me?

Comment: You want the total without summing? Good luck with that, note however that there's no need to use 2 for-loop, just print and sum in one

Comment: @RC. i want to sum it all , i just dont know how .  
can you explain me this : ` totalIm += i ` dont quite understand that and what it does ? 
and for some reason it doesnt work , im getting this error in the compiler : "- The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) int, Object

Comment: `x += y` is the same as `x = x + y`  regarding the error, you can **not** do a `+` between an `int` and an `Object` (think 2 + poney = what??). You need to cast `data[row][1]` as `long` or `int` (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html paragraph "casting")

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to create separate class that could be called `CountryImmigrants`. Such class will have four fields:

```
private String countryName;
private int immigrantsCount;
private double immigrantsPercentPop;
private double immigrantsPercentGlob;
```

Then you will just have `List<CountryImmigrants> list = ...`, and then you will be able to just write:

```
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(country -> country.getImmigrantsCount()).sum();
```

And ylso you can then override `toString()` method in `CountryImmigrants` for printing information about particular country.

Comment: i think this will work , the this is - im trying to write it all in the main 
no class usage or anything 
can you help me understand what is wrong with the option the one above you suggested ?

Comment: You can still use my suggested solution if you want to keep everything in one file because you can just create CountryImmigrants as inner class. And if you are trying to solve some problem with Java and you do not want to use classes, then why you use Java at all? I recommend you to read some Java (or other programming language) related book and follow the exercises. Make it work in your mind at first and then start writing code. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

may be bellow code help you

```
long totalImmigrants=0;
double worldTotal=0.0;
double totalPopulation=0.0;


for (int row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
    System.out.printf("%22s %12s %17s %14s\n", data[row][0], data[row][1],data[row][2], data[row][3]);
    totalImmigrants+=data[row][1];
    worldTotal+=data[row][2];
    totalPopulation+=data[row][3];
}
```

in the end of code you should just print three variables.

Comment: Some casts are missing

Answer (score -1):

```
    int totalIm =0 ;
    for(int row= 0 ;row<  data.length;row++){
       totalIm += data[row][1];
    }//  System.out.println(totalIm)
```

Comment: can you explain me this : ` totalIm += i ` dont quite understand that and what it does

Comment: and btw for some reason this doesnt work , im getting this error in the compiler : "- The operator += is undefined for the argument type(s) int, 
  Object"

Comment: A cast is missing

Comment: totalIm += is same    totalIm = totalIm+data[row][1] you need to cast like  totalIm = totalIm+(int)data[row][1]